# Objects become NaN/infinity when using j as index but when using i the objects are fine

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, nan

I am trying to call an array of planets called Planets but whenever I call the objects in the array using j, as in Planets[j]; the X and Y elements become NaN/infinity at seemingly random intervals. Whenever I call the objects using i, as in Planets[i]; the X and Y elements are totally fine. What am I doing wrong?

I tried deflating the nested for loop into a while loop, changing variables from var to let, etc., and changing conflicting variable names such as tempPlanet in generatePlanets() to hempPlanet to avoid conflict with iterate()

```js
let cv = document.getElementById("canvas");
let context = cv.getContext("2d");


let wh = window.innerHeight;
let ww = window.innerWidth;


cv.width = ww;
cv.height = wh;
cv.style.background = "#ffff12";

const numPlanets = 10;
const gridSize = 500;
const maxMass = 50
const gFactor = 0.667;
const timeScale = 1;

let Planets = [];

class Planet {
  Mass = 0;
  X = 0;
  Y = 0;
  VelX = 0;
  VelY = 0;


  constructor(X, Y, Mass, VelX, VelY) {
    var Mass = Mass;
    var X = X;
    var Y = Y;
    var VelX = VelX;
    var VelY = VelY;

  }
  getMass() {
    return this.Mass;
  }
  getX() {
    return this.X;
  }
  getY() {
    return this.Y;
  }
  getVelX() {
    return this.VelX;
  }
  getVelY() {
    return this.VelY;
  }



}

function generateMass(maxMass) {
  // ensures mass is above 1
  mass = Math.round((Math.random() * (maxMass - 1)) + 1);
  return mass;
}

function generateCoordinate(gridSize) {
  let coordinate = Math.round(Math.random() * gridSize);
  return coordinate;
}

function generatePlanets(numPlanets, maxMass, gridSize) {
  for (i = 0; i < numPlanets; i++) {
    let hempPlanet = new Planet();

    mass = generateMass(maxMass);
    x = generateCoordinate(gridSize);
    y = generateCoordinate(gridSize);

    hempPlanet.Mass = mass;
    hempPlanet.X = x;
    hempPlanet.Y = y

    Planets[i] = hempPlanet;
  }
}

function calculateDistance(x1, x2, y1, y2) {
  if (x1 > x2) {
    bigX = x1;
    littleX = x2;
  } else {
    bigX = x2;
    littleX = x1;
  }

  if (y1 > y2) {
    bigY = y1;
    littleY = y2;
  } else {
    bigY = y2;
    littleY = y1;
  }

  return Math.sqrt((bigX - littleX) ^ 2 + (bigY - littleY) ^ 2);
}

function iterate(Planets) {
  // Velocity = delta s / delta time
  // Velocity = prevpos - pos / timestep
  let i = 0;
  let j = 0;
  while (i < numPlanets) {

    // newtonian gravity = m1*m2*g/dist^2
    //unfortunately it will goober out if dist is less than one
    //so safer equation is m1*m2*g/(dist^2+5)
    // can increase the +5 to anything to make it safer but slower and less accurate

    let planet = Planets[i];
    let planetMass = planet.getMass();
    let planetX = planet.getX();
    let planetY = planet.getY();
    let planetVelX = planet.getVelX();
    let planetVelY = planet.getVelY();

    let addedPosX = 0;
    let addedPosY = 0;


    var tempPlanet = Planets[j];
    if (tempPlanet !== planet) {
      console.log(tempPlanet)
      let tempPlanetMass = tempPlanet.getMass();
      let tempPlanetX = tempPlanet.getX();
      let tempPlanetY = tempPlanet.getY();
      let tempPlanetVelX = tempPlanet.getVelX();
      let tempPlanetVelY = tempPlanet.getVelY();

      let distance = calculateDistance(tempPlanetX, planetX, tempPlanetY, planetY);

      let distX = (planetX - tempPlanetX);
      let distY = (planetY - tempPlanetY);
      let addedDist = distX + distY;
      let xMultiplier = distX / addedDist; //change in x position when multiplied by gravity
      let yMultiplier = distY / addedDist; //change in y position when multiplied by gravity

      let gravity = (planetMass + tempPlanetMass * gFactor) / (distance ^ 2 + 5);

      let gravityX = gravity * xMultiplier;
      let gravityY = gravity * yMultiplier;

      addedPosX += gravityX;
      addedPosY += gravityY;

    }
    Planets[i].X = addedPosX + planetX;
    Planets[i].Y = addedPosY + planetY;


    j++;
    if (j % numPlanets == 0) {
      i++;
      j = 0;
    }

  }
}

function drawPlanets(Planets) {
  for (i = 1; i < numPlanets; i++) {
    let planet = Planets[i];
    let planetX = planet.x;
    let planetY = planet.y;
    context.fillRect(planetX - 5, planetX, planetY - 5, planetY);
  }
}

function main() {
  generatePlanets(numPlanets, maxMass, gridSize);
  iterate(Planets);
  drawPlanets(Planets);

}
main()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: please provide a simpler example - [mcve]

Comment: Note: to prevent strange unexpected behaviour in your `for` loops, declare the `i` with `let` to ensure its scoped to just the loop, as otherwise you assign to a global variable, which might not be what you want. `for( let i = 0; ...`

Comment: You never set the VelX and VelY, and doing math operations with `undefined` will give you those results. You've written a ton of code without running it as you go. That's dangerous even for the experienced, for a beginner that's the kiss of death. Never write more than ~10 lines of code without testing it at least manually, preferably with a unit test. Else you wind up where you are now: you have dozens if not hundreds of LoC that doesn't work and you have no idea where the problem is. Also as Daniel A. White points out a smaller code example like 10~20 would be a more appropriate size for SO.

Comment: do yourself a favor: put `"use strict";` at the top of your script (see [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)) and fix all the errors.

Comment: Note that `^` is `xor`, not exponentiation. In the distance calculation, `^ 2` should be `**2` instead. More problems: The constructor takes 5 parameters, but you call it like `new Planet()`. And in the constructor, you do nothing to `this.X` etc, you just assign local variables and no further use.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out by myself. The variable names I was using for the X and Y coordinates inside the planet objects was "x" and "y", which javascript reads as NaN or infinity sometimes for some reason. This can be solved by changing the variable names to something else.